# Limit of derivative does not exist, while limit of difference quotient is infinite

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone show an example of a function $f$ of a real variabile such that

- $f$ is differentiable on a neighborhood of a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, except at $x_0$ itself;
- $f$ is continuous at $x_0$;
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x)$ does not exist;
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} = +\infty$ or $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} = -\infty$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x}+x\sin\frac{1}{x}$$

defined on $(0,+\infty)$, that can be defined by continuity at $0$ with $f(0)=0$? (I let you check that it works, if I am not wrong)

If you don't like it because it is only $\mathbb{R}_+$, you can replace with

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}+x\sin\frac{1}{x},$$

[graph](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/x%5E%28-2/3%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=KhS5VqKxBoXxaIKPqfgH#q=x%5E%281/3%29%2Bx*sin%281/x%29%29)

that can be defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Using google, you get a fairly obvious drawing explaining what is happening (personally before having an explicit example, I had a fairly good drawing in my head to convince myself that such an example was possible, and then help me to produce a formula)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain a bit more how you convinced yourself that such an example was possible and how you ''produced'' it?

Comment: Ok; your last requirement was asking for a vertical tangent at 0. The previous one, about the limit of $f'$ near 0, is concerned with the behaviour of $f'$ near 0, namely, you expect that your curve is oscillating a lot (though the size of oscillations are small as $f$ is continuous), which is feasible and not in contradiction with the vertical tangent.
Therefore, the solution is the sum of $\sqrt{x}$ which provides a vertical tangent and $x\sin(1/x)$ which is a classical oscillating continuous function

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}=x^{1/3}$ [[Graph]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=plot+surd(x,3))?

$f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$. Notice that $f'(x)$ exists everywhere except at $x=0$. Also, $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous everywhere.

However, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^{1/3}-0^{1/3}}{x-0} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x^{2/3}} = +\infty$.

While this curve is continuous, it has a vertical tangent at $x=0$ (resulting in the "infinite" derivative there).

[If you choose $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}=x^{2/3}$, you'll get a similar example where the limit definition of the derivative gives $\pm \infty$ as you approach $0$ from the left and right.]

Comment: Well, the limit at 0 of $f'(x)$ when $x$ goes to 0 exists, to my understanding... it is $+\infty$!

Comment: Umm...no. Not in the usual sense of a limit existing. Limits = +/- infinity are just special kinds of *divergence*. Yes, in an extended sense, the derivative at zero is infinity. But in the standard accepted definition of differentiability this function isn't differentiable at zero because the limit doesn't exist  (as a real number) there.

Comment: Well, it is a question of definition, but to my point of view, no existence of a limit, when dealing with real numbers, usually means doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$. Similarly, the word "divergence" is never really clear... Of course, your definition makes sense too, but the notion of a "usual" definition is something vague to my point of view... only @Paolo knows what he meant
(ps: I never said your function was differentiable at 0)

Comment: When I wrote $\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x)$ does not exist, I meant that it is not finite and it is neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$. I'm afraid I wasn't very clear in my question. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two semicircles joining when $x=x_0$ such as

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1-(x_0+1-x)^2} \text{ when } x_0 \le x \le x_0+2$$
$$f(x) = -\sqrt{1-(x_0-1-x)^2} \text{ when } x_0-2 \le x \le x_0$$

Change the signs if you want alternative limits for the derivatives as $x \to x_0$